# iPhone SDK - Touch a UIButton through a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to capture a touch through a `UILabel`, but am having trouble. Here is my scenario. 
I have a `UIButton` as a subview of a `UIScrollView`. I also have a `UILabel` as a subview of the same `UIScrollView`. The frame of the UILabel overlaps that of the UIButton, and thus (as far as I can tell) occludes the `UIButton` from being pressed.

I am trying to create a scenario where the user can touch through the `UILabel` (it has a transparent background, so the button is completely visible - less the labels text).

**Is this possible?**

I know touches behave differently when there is a `UIScrollView` involved. Is that impeding the touches?

Anyone have any advice?
Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creating transparent UIButton on top of UILabel that too inside a UIScrollView is a design issue for me. If you have to do it then you don't have a choice. It won't work seamlessly though. Don't expect users not to complain. If I don't see a button there and scrolling through the view accidentally triggers button action then I am irritated.
It is possible to create such UI.